# Modelling a 'web' in a Django database

Tags: django, database

I have a use case where I have a 'web' with the following relationships; what's the best way to model this in Django?

1. There is a logical top layer (could be modelled as a single 'very top' node if required)
2. There are logical leaves at the bottom
3. Nodes can have relationships to nodes in the layer above and/or below but never to siblings

So like that chinese game with a coin dropping through pins, there are multiple routes from top to bottom but a traversal will always work, albeit in some manner determined elsewherre (actually user input in my case).

I have tried using ManyToMany relationships but can't see how to spot the top and bottom of the relationships; do I need to switch to many OneToMany relationships for independent child and parent relationships?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can make this kind of graph explicit in the data structure, but you can enfore it with semantic actions in the creation/update of nodes. Let's say you have a model of a Node:

```py
class Node(models.Model):
    connections = ManyToManyField(Node)
    layer_level = IntegerField(null=False, default=1)
```

In the constructor and the magic setter `__setattr__` you can then check if the connections of the node all have a layer level greater or less than the node itself and raise an exception if they're equal. I admit that it's possible that in Django "interjecting" the setting of fields of a model instance is more complicated than overriding the `__setattr__` method, but that's beyond the scope of this answer.

The point is that you can set up a model that your desired structure but with less restrictions and then enforce the restrictions on creation/update, rather than making them implicit in the model structure. The latter would be a better solution, but also one that is likely not possible with relational databases and/or Django's ORM.

Comment: Etienne, thanks for the response and the layer level.  Ignoring that for a moment, I discovered a bug in my code where I was adding relationships from both directions and having fixed that, things worked.  What I had done was:
1. Create a manytomany relationship from object type X to X called `parents`
2. Used the `related_name` option to create  `children` in the opposite direction.
3. Always do `child_object.add(parents)` and never the other way around.
Now the top can be identified by `..filter(parents__id__isnull=True) and similarly for children at the bottom.